# Updating an item in Redux using ImmutableJS given a key

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

## Redux State:

```
let initialState = Immutable.fromJS({
  budgetItems: [],
  editingBudget: [[]]
});
```

Trying to update items in the `budgetItems` section, which is an array of objects.

The structure of the objects in the array is like:

```
  let initBudget = {budgetCategory: '', budgetCost: '', budgetDate: ''};
```

## My attempt:

```
case types.UPDATE_EXISTING_BUDGET:
  return state.getIn(['budgetItems']).update(
    state.getIn(['budgetItems']).findIndex(function(item) {
      return item.get("budgetCategory") === action.payload.budgetCategory;
    }), function(item) {
      return item.set(action.payload.budgetCategory);
    }
  );
```

Trying to literally replace the entire object that I've found. The above code is working if I set a single key with a value, but not the entire object

Answer (score 0):

To update an object or an array you'll need the [`updateIn`  method](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/updateIn).

```
import { fromJS, List, Map } from immutable;

const initialState = fromJS({
  data: List([Map({ foo: { bar: baz } } })],
});

functionFooReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE:
      return state
        .updateIn(['data.0.foo.bar'.split('.')], (), action.value);
    // ...
  }
}
```